# Select last 7 days records by date and avoid duplicates by specific column

Tags: php, sql, date

I'm pretty sure the problem I'm facing is quite small, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

I have the following table in my sql:

```
+-----+------------------+---------------------+
| ID  | EMAIL            | VISIT               |
+-----+------------------+---------------------+
| 1   | john@email.com   | 2021-04-01,13:20:23 |
| 2   | peter@email.com  | 2021-04-03,12:03:44 |
| 3   | daniel@email.com | 2021-04-04,13:21:12 |
| 4   | john@email.com   | 2021-04-06,09:34:31 |
| 5   | peter@email.com  | 2021-04-07,11:20:22 |
+-----+------------------+---------------------+
```

I want to display the last 7 days records but ordered by newest date and showing only the newest record by each email, like this

```
+-----+------------------+---------------------+
| ID  | EMAIL            | VISIT               |
+-----+------------------+---------------------+
| 3   | daniel@email.com | 2021-04-04,13:21:12 |
| 4   | john@email.com   | 2021-04-06,09:34:31 |
| 5   | peter@email.com  | 2021-04-07,11:20:22 |
+-----+------------------+---------------------+
```

I've tried this query to achieve this:

Attempt 1: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE VISIT BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() GROUP BY EMAIL ORDER BY VISIT DESC`

Attempt 2: `SELECT DISTINCT (EMAIL) FROM table WHERE VISIT BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() ORDER BY VISIT DESC`

The results are displayed correctly, but in a strange order.
If I give up GROUP BY clause, it displays correctly but also includes EMAIL column duplicates.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using  MAX with group by

```
SELECT EMAIL,MAX(VISIT)  as last_visit FROM table WHERE VISIT BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()  GROUP BY EMAIL ORDER BY last_visit DESC
```

Comment: This will include **all** distinct EMAIL and VISIT pairs, however OP asked for only the latest visit on each email address.

Comment: updated kindly check

Comment: Yeah, now works corectly. I only removed MAX(VISIT) from select part and i keep it only on order part because was problems with printing VISIT values. But now everything is ok. Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually i was wrong. It's not printing the newest VISIT value after I removed MAX(VISIT). How can I print/echo time value with SELECT MAX(VISIT)? Because now it shows me dates from 1970.

Comment: most welcome , 
you can add alias to the column to be like that 

`SELECT EMAIL,MAX(VISIT)  as last_visit FROM table WHERE VISIT BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()  GROUP BY EMAIL ORDER BY last_visit DESC;` 

then echo last_visit

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this code to you: ‌

```
SELECT
    EMAIL
FROM `table_name`
WHERE
    VISIT BETWEEN(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY
    EMAIL
ORDER BY
    MAX(VISIT)
DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a subquery to number the rows within each group, then select from this subquery only the first rows in each group:

```
SELECT EMAIL, VISIT FROM (
    SELECT EMAIL, VISIT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMAIL ORDER BY VISIT DESC) AS 'RowNumber' 
    FROM table 
    WHERE VISIT>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
) T1
WHERE RowNumber=1
```